# How to handle nested transaction exception in spring integration

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-transactions

I have a DB-based channel and a simple integration flow like following:

```
        return IntegrationFlows.from("messageChannel")
                .handle(messageHandler, "process", consumer ->
                        consumer.poller(poller -> poller
                                .fixedDelay(3000)
                                .transactional()
                                .transactionSynchronizationFactory(messageStoreSynchronizationFactory)
                                .taskExecutor(taskExecutor)
                                .receiveTimeout(1000)
                                .maxMessagesPerPoll(10)))
                .get();
```

As a part of message processing (`messageHandler.process`) I need to open nested transactions to reach out to other databases. The problem is that any unhandled exception that might be thrown from a nested transaction sets my parent transaction to `rollback-only` which puts my message back to the channel. That creates a loop that blocks the channel until an issue with a nested transaction is fixed.

In theory, I should catch and handle exceptions within a nested transaction and never propagate to the parent one but it's hard to enforce that with my current project architecture.

Removing `.transactional()` from the poller removes parent transaction out of the picture and "fixes" the issue but then it never calls transaction synchronization factory (which makes sense).

Is there a way to allow the nested transaction to throw an exception and still process the message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either add a `.gateway()` mid-flow and handle the exception via it's `errorChannel` or you can add an `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice` (or custom advice) to the handler's endpoint to handle the exception there.

See [Adding Behavior to Endpoints](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/messaging-endpoints.html#message-handler-advice-chain).

Comment: Gary, thank you for your response. I tried both approaches but whether I use custom advice or gateway it still rolls back parent transaction and puts the message back to the original channel.

Comment: Edit the question to show what you tried.

Comment: The workaround that seems to work is using ```Propagation.NESTED``` on child transactions within ```messageHandler.process``` method. That way even if nested transaction throws an unhandled exception the parent transaction will not be set to ```rollback-only``` and is still going to commit.